# Why am I having trouble filtering by date and time using lubridate?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a data frame, and I'm trying to keep records after 10:05 AM on 1/22/21.

```
df1$`Date/Time Opened` <- as_datetime(df1$`Date/Time Opened`)

df2 <- df1 %>% filter("Date/Time Opened" > as_datetime("2021-01-22 10:05:00"))
```

It throws this error when I try to filter:

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
i Input `..1` is `"Date/Time Opened" > as_datetime("2021-01-22 10:05:00")`.
```

If I use `as.numeric(as_datetime("2021-01-22 10:05:00"))` or `as.character(as_datetime("2021-01-22 10:05:00"))` it runs without throwing an error, but the filter is not applied correctly. (Either all or none of the records are filtered out.)

Comment: Shouldn't the variable in the `filter` function not be in quotes? df1 %>% filter(`Date/Time Opened` > as_datetime("2021-01-22 10:05:00")) ? (note that you need back ticks ( `) around the Date/Time Opened variable name)

Comment: `df2 <- df1 %>% filter(\`Date/Time Opened\` > as_datetime("2021-01-22 10:05:00"))`

Comment: thank you both! using back ticks instead of quotes fixed it!